# How to adjust the thickness of the lines depending on the distance to the camera?

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, lineart

I use Line Art Modifier to draw my mesh by grease pencil lines. I would like to adjust the thickness of this lines depending on the distance to the camera.

Is it possible to do it somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a suggestion based on @Benus' answer that doesn't require baking the line art modifier, but offers less initial control on the starting thickness :

Add a Line Art Object (Add > Grease Pencil > Scene Line Art)

Add a Vertex Group :

[image]

Add a [Vertex Weight Proximity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/modify/weight_proximity.html) modifier and a [Thickness](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modifiers/deform/thickness.html) modifier.

Play with the Lowest and Highest values and set the new vertex group in both modifiers. check "Weighted" in the Thickness modifier.

[image]

Before :

[image]

After :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Bake the Line Art.

[image]

Create a new Vertex Group, select all vertices and Assign.

[image]

Add a Vertex Weight Proximity modifier. Select the newly created vertex group. Select Camera as Target Object. Adjust Lowest and Highest to set how close you want the minimum thickness and how far you want the maximum. Check Multiply Weights. This is useful if you want to keep the current thickness offsets.

Add a Thickness modifier. Check the Weighted option. Under Influence, set Vertex Group to the newly created group.

Add another Thickness modifier. Use this to add extra thickness on top as an offset.

Without proximity modifier:

[image]

With proximity modifier:

[image]