# How can I create organic, tapered "ribbon" landscapes in Blender using Grease Pencil?

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart, lines

I am relatively new to Blender and am working on a landscape look inspired by these "ribbon" illustrations.

[image]

So far, I have been using a simple shader with a wave texture combined with some noise to create lines that run over a landscape. This landscape was created using a plane and displacement.

[image]
[image]

While this approach has yielded some progress, I would like to improve the appearance of the lines by using Grease Pencil. This would allow me to create tapered, roughened lines with a more organic feel and allow me to create variation on the distance between lines and their paths.

Additionally, I would like to adjust the thickness of the lines based on their distance from the camera, to achieve a more uniform appearance [similar to this example.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/250029/how-to-adjust-the-thickness-of-the-lines-depending-on-the-distance-to-the-camera)

Any guidance on how to achieve these effects using Grease Pencil would be greatly appreciated.

Edit. I am wondering if this is perhaps a job for geometry nodes + grease pencil. I am going to investigate this.

Comment: I think it's probably a good idea to do it with grease pencil, but you could certainly take material nodes approach way further as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I worked on a geometry-node with grease pencil grid/line thing today and it was a bit of a no-go as I am unable to control the instances individually. In addition to this, I tried working with an array of very thin planes and an array modifier. Again this was less flexible that the displacement mapped plane and material nodes. I am in agreement with you that I can take this approach further. I think it's the most flexible and efficient workflow. Thanks for your input.